# The icon is cached when creating a style in the GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I create a style in the GeoServer using CSS.
I add the URL for the image as shown below.

```
{
    mark: url(../images/marker.png);
    mark-mime: "image/png";
    mark-size: 25px;
    mark-offset: 0 -11px;
}
```

I have a certain picture at this address. When I change it with a PUT request
`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/resource/images/marker.png` the image is cached and not updated. What can be done?

Answer (score 2):

GeoServer is indeed caching the images, constantly fetching them would cause a significant slowdown. There is no way to disable this behavior, but you can drop the cache by going in the GeoServer admin console, in the "status" page, and click on the resource cache "clear" button.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there an API for deletion?

Comment: The REST API can be used to call the "reset" which is the same as the clear button (does the exact same thing). No API specific to icon caching exists. See https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/reset.html